# Export Iibre office database table to text file or csv file

Tags: database, export-to-csv, libreoffice-base

I have a Libre Office database table that I want to export or save as a .csv file. Is there any way to do this? I have been searching for a long time. I can write a very little bit in Java but would need some code suggestion in that case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just right click the database you want to export and select copy, create a new [Calc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreOffice_Calc) spreadsheet, paste the data into the spreadsheet, and then export it from the "file" menu however you like.

[Source](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Importing_and_Exporting_Data_in_Base).